# installing PyUserInput on OS X

Tags: python, appkit

I was trying to install PyUserInput on os x El Capitan, but I couldn't manage to do so.
In the git repository instructions it is written that Quartz and AppKit are needed, but I can't figure out how to install them.

I would appreciate your help, Thanks!

Comment: If my answer helps you, please mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Whenever you have to install dependencies, you should look into the package manager for the programming language (or operating system). In your case, the package manager for Python is [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip).

You can use the package managers through your shell (command prompt, terminal, etc.)

[Quartz](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyobjc-framework-Quartz/3.0.4). 
You can find the documentation [here](https://pythonhosted.org/pyobjc/)

```
pip install -U pyobjc
```

[AppKit](http://nitipit.github.io/appkit/). 
You can find the documentation [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/AppKit/0.2.8)

```
pip install appkit
```

Then, you can install [PyUserInput](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyUserInput/0.1.10). 
The repo for PyUserInput is [here](https://github.com/SavinaRoja/PyUserInput).

Comment: thanks for the reply!
I tried this already (pip install -U pyobjc), but I get an error:
`
Failed building wheel for pyobjc-framework-CoreLocation

1 error generated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/__/9_lksj9x5lj8m9s299500nd00000gn/T/pip-build-3sjnty/pyobjc-framework-CoreLocation`

and when I tried to install appkit I got:
Building PyGObject using distutils is only supported on windows. *
    * To build PyGObject in a supported way, read the INSTALL file.

Do you know how to solve it?